# USB file transfer with Python

Tags: python, usb

I need to read a text file stored on a USB stick. PyUSB is what I need to search the USB device, but I don't understand how can I access the file after the device is mounted (on Linux and on Windows).

An idea please?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the absolute path of the file (e.g. `C:\text.txt`).

To loop through the lines of a text file, use

```
for line in open("C:\text.txt", "rU"):
    #do stuff
```

Comment: Best to use either `open(r"C:\text.txt"...)` or `open("C:\\text.txt"...)` - although '/' on Windows still works...

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu the pendrive was under /media so I used:

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/media'):
    print root, "consumes",
    print sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files),
    print "bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files"
```

from http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk

in windows you will have to try with different drive letters maybe?

No need for PyUSB.

Comment: Hmm, my question is not good. I know how to open a file, but not how to find where the usb stick is mounted after it was plugged in.

Comment: Use [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) with try/except to open the folder of the pendrive. Maybe with a list of probable names.